# Display: none not working as expect using @media

Tags: css, responsive

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXq43.png)
[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj9Nl.png)

I have two forms which include a search box.

1. desktop-search
2. mobile-search

My plan is to make the search box move down into it's own row.
I hide one when on desktop and display the other, and vice verse for the mobile version.

desktop-search is displayed for widths bigger than 765px and disappears for anything less than that, as planned.

However, mobile-search is ALWAYS there, no matter the width.

```html
    @media screen and (max-width: 765px) {
      .desktop-search {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 766px) {
      .mobile-search {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Have you tried `display: none!important`?